# My chilli plant is leaning away from the vertical, should I support it somehow?

Tags: chili, support

My plant is quite young, about 20 cm tall. It is leaning slightly, should I support it? If so, how?

Comment: Hello, Cammil! For a useful answer a photo would be best.

Comment: I've noticed that if you top a pepper at a certain height, it'll get bushier, and be less likely to fall over. Also, a leaning plant at a young age might indicate that it could use more nutrients that help its structure (e.g. potassium, calcium and/or silica). Also, you might try seasoning peppers like Aji Dulce 1, Grenada Seasoning, etc. (they grow bushy naturally).

Answer (score 4):

Staking is generally recommended but not required for pepper plants.  The benefits of staking are support for the mainstem, branches and fruits, keeping the plant upright, reducing sunscald on fruits and keeping fruits off the ground which prevents rot/pests.

To [stake peppers](https://bonnieplants.com/library/peppers-to-stake-or-not-to-stake/) it is best to do so at transplant time or soon after to avoid damaging roots.  Drive a metal or wooden stake next to each plant and then tie the main-stem loosely.  You can also tie any branches in need of support to the same stake.  Alternatively, some people like to use tomato cages so that branches can drape over the frame for support.

Comment: I totally agree. Additionally, chili and pepper seems to have small roots, so staking really helps (especially in windy places).

Comment: I have to add that staking and supporting a seasonal plant is fine and recommended.  Just remember that staking and supporting plants is like a cast on your arm or leg...causes atrophy of its own support system.  Don't do this with trees or woody perennials unless there is a major catastrophe.

Comment: You might need support for the heaviness of the fruit- as a leaning plant will simply just break under the stress- a small stake and remember to tie the plant to the stake not the other way round! avoids damage to the stem.